# How to solve the sandbox Error in Windows 7 and Windows 8

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script

Here placed code for i have created Dashboard page using Google AppScript and Google Sheet. and this code displayed good displayed in Windows 10 and latest but below said the error showing in Windows7 & Windows8. How To fix

Console Error : Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-storage-access-by-user-activation' is an invalid sandbox flag.

Google AppScript Code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (!e.parameter.page) {
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Dashboard');
    return htmlOutput.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Dashboard')      
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
      .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you check this 

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output\#setSandboxMode(SandboxMode)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setSandboxMode\(SandboxMode\)) ?